# UDP Client in Java (Android) for getting Data from X-Plane 12

Tags: java, android, udp

I try to read the UDP Stream from X-Plane 12 in Java.
This is what I try:

```
public class EchoClient {
@Test
public void echo() throws IOException {
    DatagramSocket socket;
    InetAddress address;

    byte[] buf;
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
    address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    String msg = "TEST";
    buf = msg.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet
            = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, 49000);
    socket.send(packet);
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    System.out.println("hi there");
    while(true) {
        socket.receive(packet); // it "stops" here... without an error 
        String received = new String(
                packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
        System.out.println(received);
    }
}}
```

X-Plane is running and the UDP option is activated - but my program does print nothing on the console.. and it is runnig forever (while true)

Answer (score 0):

Receive is blocked and waiting to a receive a packet. The packet you sent earlier is dropped on the floor because no one is listening.

Comment: why is it blocked? X-Plane is running, its UDP Socket is running on the port 49000 - The packet is dropped? O_o Don't drop the durka durk! Where could the problem be?

Comment: The send occurs before receive. There is no one to send to. 

Try putting your listening while loop into a new thread, that is initialized BEFORE you call socket.send()